# Soap vs Rest over Android

Tags: android, rest, soap

I am creating an app in android. It will be calling a webservice to fetch some confidential info. I need to verify that the user is authenticated to access the info and the service shouldn't be called from any other source even if the user has all the required credentails to access the service.

What should be used to ensure the security.... REST or SOAP?

Comment: Does the server use REST or SOAP?

Comment: I have to decide what the server will be using. So it can use any protocol. I am getting a feeling that usage of either protocol is a matter of personal preference. Any comments???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security you should use SSL  with client authentification  and possibility to revoke cvlient certificates (though not every appplication server will support this).  SOAP or REST do not have differences in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience REST is easier to build and has less overhead. I used to build soap services with CXF, which is really easy, but now I use Restlet for the server, which is even easier and quicker. Restlet has integration for Json, Guice, JPA, and all the good stuff. At the Android side, I use a simple rest interface with httpClient, Roboguice and Jackson.